# 0-5V supply to control brightness of BWTek spectroscopy light source

Tags: power-supply, power

I recently installed a BWTek BPS101 tungsten halogen light source and would like to take advantage of the builtin support for manipulating the operating current (changing the brightness) via an external power supply.

The manual says gives a pinout where pin 1 is ground and pin 2 is "Analog control input". 0 VDC corresponds to minimum power output and 5 VDC corresponds to maximum power output. The pinout doesn't provide a 5 VDC rail at all. It also says:

> You must make sure that the input current from the Power Supply matches the impedance of the light source. If they do not match, a proper Current to Voltage curve will not be obtainable.

The manual specifies the device's input resistance is 3.5 kOhms.

How do I design a circuit that won't fry this expensive instrument but will let me variably control the power of the light source?

Answer (score 1):

The [data sheet](http://www.snowhouse.ca/pdf/BWTek%20-%20BPS101%20(Tungsten%20Halogen%20Light%20Source).pdf) says:

> Modulation Input DC 0-5 V to Set Output Power

Looks to me like the comment on 'matching' refers to the power supply rather than the control input.

So you need a solid power supply capable of > 1.1A for the lamp and controller and an input signal suitable for a 3.5K input Z.

A simple way to get that would be to use a 5V series reference such as a [AD1582-85](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD1582_1583_1584_1585.pdf) from the 6V supply (needs to have a low dropout voltage), add a pot (say 10K) from 5V to GND and buffer the output with an op-amp voltage follower such as an [LT1637](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1637fd.pdf) that can handle inputs down to the negative rail and to within 1V of the positive rail, and has output with 3.5K load that will get within 1V of the positive supply rail. Power the op-amp from the 6V supply.

Damage is most likely to come from an incorrectly wired unit, or a power supply that is out of spec.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they could mean two things; one being that the dimming supply must be a voltage source stiff enough to supply 0 to 5 volts into a 3500 ohm load, and the other being that the output impedance of the supply must be 3500 ohms.

In order to find out which, you could put a 3600 ohm resistor in series with your 5 volt supply output and feed the analog control input with the output from the resistor, and if that won't get you from full dark to nearly full bright try the naked 0 to 5 volt output from your supply.

Of course, you could always call/email them and get the answer from the horse's mouth.